# In Old Man's War why do they hold back technology from Earth?

Tags: novel, old-mans-war

In *Old Man's War*, why do they hold back technology from Earth?

Does the CDF want to withhold technologies related to cloning and consciousness transfer to preserve their recruiting base for soldiers and colonists?

What about other technology?  Why not station defenses at Earth?  What is the motive to keep Earth in the dark?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does the CDF want to withhold technologies related to cloning and consciousness transfer to preserve their recruiting base for soldiers and colonists?

In one word: yes.

This is spelled out explicitly in some of the sequels, especially the recent series "The Human Division".

Comment: Ok I'm on Ghost Brigades right now.  Would it be a spoiler to reveal why it's withheld from Earth?

Comment: @anataliocs: you've already stated the "why" yourself: because it gives them an enormous, steady supply of colonists and soldiers whom they can use as cannon fodder without having to worry about civil unrest at home.

Comment: But why do the Obin want a backwater resource-depleted planet like Earth so bad?  There has to be more to it.  Sorry I'll shut up and just read the book.

Comment: @anataliocs the Obin didn't really want Earth.  They wanted something else, and the person that had what the Obin really wanted was the the person interested in Earth.  The Obin were going to capture it only as part of a deal to get something else they wanted.